# How do I access a module from a package using Python's zipimport?

Tags: python, python-2.7, package

I wrote a simple Python package using python's paster, where my package has the directory structure:

```
pkg/
    __init__.py
    module1.py
    subpackage/
        __init__.py
        module2.py
```

The **init**.py files are blank and module1.py contains a function that imports something from module2.py.  I install the package and I'm able to call functions in module1.py from the python prompt:

```
import pkg.module1
```

I go to where the package was installed (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg/) and zip the pkg directory:

```
zip -r pkg.zip pkg/
```

I try to access the module from the python prompt using zipimport:

```
import zipimport
importer = zipimport.zipimporter('pkg.zip')
importer.find_module('pkg')
# <zipimporter object "pkg.zip">
importer.load_module('pkg')
# <module 'pkg' from 'pkg.zip/pkg/__init__.pyc'>
importer.is_package('pkg')
# True
pkg = importer.load_module('pkg')
# trying to call a function in module 1 called fcn1
pkg.module1.fcn1()
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'module1'
pkg.module1
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'module1'
```

Any ideas on how to access module1?  Thanks.

Comment: What do you get if you call `dir(pkg)` that may help?

Comment: I get: ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I looked at other established packages like bs4, their `__init__.py` files had code that allowed you to access other modules.  For example, the class `BeautifulSoup` is in the `__init__.py` file.  If someone knows how to access modules without changing the original code, that would be great.  Otherwise, changing `__init__.py` works.

Comment: beautifulsoup4-4.4.1.zip/bs4 folder - the module will be imported:
`bs4_importer = zipimporter('beautifulsoup4-4.4.1.zip')
bs4 = bs4_importer.load_module('bs4')`

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./pkg.zip') # Or path to pkg.zip
import module1

module1.fcn1()
```

This will use `zipimport` for you.

I think that you may need to list the public parts of your module in it's **init**.py file take a look at [PEP 273](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0273/)

Comment: When I try to import module1 I get the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named module1.  Any ideas?  If not, thanks for trying.

Comment: @user1910316 if Steve Barnes code snippet above was in say main.py then pkg.zip would need to be in the same directory as main.py as it is written. It likely didn't work because pkg.zip was not in same directory. Also zip files with comments at one time did not work. Also check your zip file and make sure it is not 'pkg.zip\pkg\__init__.py' instead of just `pkg.zip\__init__.py`. Also make sure there is not a pkg.zip in your PYTHONPATH that is not in fact a Python package.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a step. If your package was not in a zip file, you would do:

```
import pkg
import pkg.module1   # You did not do this.
result = pkg.module1.fnc1()
```

OR file contents of `pkg\__init__.py` could instead be:

```
import module1 # __init__.py does it for you.
```

Comment: i try zip import at osx and use Python 3.6.5; i think you mean client code must import zip by file name manually FIRST